# Redirect in html <object>

Tags: html

I'm using the `<object>` tag to display a website in my website (instead of `<iframe>`).

```
<object id="iframe" type="text/html" data="http://website.com"></object>
```

The problem is that if the website in the `<object>` redirects, my own website will be redirected.
I do not have this problem with `<iframe>`. Ideas?

Comment: Use `iframe`...

Comment: As mentioned by Bart, there is no reason to use `<object>` over `<iframe>` so why use object? Perhaps if you can explain why you are using `<object>` over `<iframe>` we might be able to help better.

Comment: For some reason the website Im trying to display does not work with iframe

Comment: Why is it not working with an `<iframe>`? Can you show what you tried?

Comment: Yes, it's this website I'm trying to display: http://www.ica.se/butiker/supermarket/arboga/ica-supermarket-asplunds-1022/start/

Answer (score -2):

Try this. It is working.

```
<object width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid red;" data="http://php.net" type="application/html" archive="http://php.net">
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/SUSeP/)